# Inserting Increment Values into Table Pt 2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote the following script to insert values into a table.
I am receiving an error message when trying to insert value for one of the columns called column A
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'A', table 'TEST_VALIDATION.dbo.TableA'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

I have tried declaring a variable for this value being declared. The value I am having problems with is the @insertswid invarchar(100) Variable
It should be incrementing the name Spinweb + 1 for each line. Example first row column A should equal Spinweb1, row 2 Spinweb 2 and so on.

```
   Declare @count int = 1
   Declare @lot nvarchar = 'StressTestAuto'
   Declare @lotno nvarchar(10) = 1
   Declare @insertlot nvarchar(100)
   Declare @spinwebid nvarchar = 'SpinWeb'
   Declare @webid nvarchar(10) = 1
   Declare @insertswid nvarchar(100)
   While @count<= 100   
Begin
    set @insertlot = @lot + @lotno
    set @insertlot = @spinwebid + @webid
    Insert into CREATE_PRDO_EWS (SpinwebABI , SAPPONo, 
    ItemCodeFinish, PlannedQty, WhseFinish, ItemCodeStart, StartQty, 
    WhseStart, ParentLotNo) values (Cast(@insertswid as nvarchar(100)), 0, 
    'Lynx', 
    430, 'E_CHD', 'WA00N44A', 1, 'E_CHD', Cast(@insertlot as 
    nvarchar(100)))
    Set @count = @count + 1
    Set @lotno = @lotno + 1
    Set @webid = @webid + 1
End
```

Comment: What TEST_VALIDATION.dbo.TableA , what  column 'A' ?

Comment: My apologies, the column is called SpinWebABI

Answer (score 0):

you did not set your `@insertswid`

```
Declare @count int = 1
Declare @lot nvarchar = 'StressTestAuto'
Declare @lotno nvarchar(10) = 1
Declare @insertlot nvarchar(100)
Declare @spinwebid nvarchar = 'SpinWeb'
Declare @webid nvarchar(10) = 1
Declare @insertswid nvarchar(100)
While @count<= 100
    Begin
     set @insertlot = @lot + @lotno
     set @insertswid = @spinwebid + @webid
     Insert into CREATE_PRDO_EWS (SpinwebABI , SAPPONo, 
        ItemCodeFinish, PlannedQty, WhseFinish, ItemCodeStart, StartQty, 
        WhseStart, ParentLotNo) values (Cast(@insertswid as nvarchar(100)), 0, 
        'Lynx', 
        430, 'E_CHD', 'WA00N44A', 1, 'E_CHD', Cast(@insertlot as 
        nvarchar(100)))
     Set @count = @count + 1
     Set @lotno = @lotno + 1
     Set @webid = @webid + 1
    End
```